# Trimming UTF8 buffer

Tags: c++, c

I have a buffer with UTF8 data. I need to remove the leading and trailing spaces. 
Here is the C code which does it (in place) for ASCII buffer:

```
char *trim(char *s)
{
  while( isspace(*s) )
    memmove( s, s+1, strlen(s) );
  while( *s && isspace(s[strlen(s)-1]) )
    s[strlen(s)-1] = 0;
  return s;
}
```

How to do the same for UTF8 buffer in C/C++?

P.S.
Thanks for perfomance tip regarding strlen(). Back to UTF8 specific: what if I need to remove all spaces all together, not only at beginning and at the tail? Also I may need to remove all characters with ASCII code <32. Is any specific here  for UTF8 case, like using mbstowcs()?

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to remove all of the various Unicode spaces too, or just ASCII spaces? In the latter case you don't need to modify the code at all.

In any case, the method you're using that repeatedly calls `strlen` is extremely inefficient. It turns a simple `O(n)` operation into at least `O(n^2)`.

**Edit:** Here's some code for your updated problem, assuming you only want to strip ASCII spaces and control characters:

```
unsigned char *in, *out;
for (out = in; *in; in++) if (*in > 32) *out++ = *in;
*out = 0;
```

Comment: not to mention moving the whole string (# of spaces at the front) times

Comment: in addition to the many calls of `strlen`, all the calls to `memmove` doesn't help much either.

Comment: It would be better to find the first non-space at the start and where spaces start on the end (if any).  Then manipulate the string in one swoop.

Comment: Thanks for performance tip. Back to UTF8 specific: what if I need to remove all spaces alltogether, not only at beginning and at the tail?  Also I may need to remove all characters with ASCII code <32. Is any specific for UTF8 case?

Comment: Again, what constitutes a "space"? Without you answering that it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: @vantive98, the beauty of UTF8 is that many old character techniques still work on it as long as you're not interested in detecting or modifying any characters that take up more than one byte. For the constraints you've named thus far this code is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

strlen() scans to the end of the string, so calling it multiple times, as in your code, is very inefficient.

Try looking for the first non-space and the last non-space and then memmove the substring:

```
char *trim(char *s)
{
  char *first;
  char *last;

  first = s;
  while(isspace(*first))
    ++first;

  last = first + strlen(first) - 1;
  while(last > first && isspace(*last))
    --last;

  memmove(s, first, last - first + 1);
  s[last - first + 1] = '\0';

  return s;
}
```

Also remember that the code modifies its argument.